# ¿Como enviar archivos de un servidor a otro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Buen día, tengo la siguiente situación tengo un servidor VPS con ubuntu y tengo una carpeta llamada indicadores, donde todos los días nos envían archivos son registros de pronósticos, bien la cuestión es que esos archivos los necesito enviar a otro servidor mediante sftp puerto 22. 
Estuve investigando que scp es una opción.
Podrían ayudarme con un ejemplo o guiarme con algo parecido.
 Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tan sencillo como leer la sintaxis de `scp`:

```
$ scp
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
```

O el manual con `man scp`.

Si quieres traerte el contenido de *indicadores* a tu PC local.

```
$ scp user@server:/ruta/de/indicadores/* /mi/ruta/local/
```

O a la inversa:

```
$ scp /mi/ruta/local/* user@server:/ruta/de/indicadores/
```